# Qt: Maintain GUI controls across the platforms

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm writing a Qt GUI application that works on Linux and Windows. 
I have been able to deploy it on Linux and Windows with supporting shared libraries of respective platforms.

It runs absolutely fine on Windows and Linux except that controls do not appear as expected on Linux when I run the deployed binaries. e.g. QGroupBox is not at all seen and buttons and text label sizes are not as I had set.

**If I run through Qt Creator on Linux, controls look alright.** 
Are there any specific files for UI which I need to deploy along with other required shared libraries to make sure that controls look fine across all platforms?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting layouts (either grid layouts or form layouts) on the widgets and setting a top level layout? It sounds like they might be manually placed and not in layouts.

Comment: Did I understand right that you want to change natural platform look'n'feel of application?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run you program with parameters `-style windowsxp`. Also you should look at `QStyle` and its derivatives. In several cases you'll have to write platform-dependent code, like:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Raised);
#else
    label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Sunken);
#endif
statusBar->addWidget(label);
```